# REST API - GET Method with input parameter as JAVA Object in body

Tags: java, rest, api, get, specifications

That's my current REST GET method.

```
@GET
@Path("/URI/{input1}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<T> getDetails(@PathParam("input1") String input1) throws ServiceException;
```

Now I want to add 3 more input parameters. Instead of adding all 4 parameters as pathparams, can I create a POJO object with all 4 input parameters and pass that POJO to GET method like this

```
@GET
@Path("/URI")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<T> getDetails(InputPojo input) throws ServiceException;
```

POJO class with input parameters:

```
class InputPojo {
    String input1;
    String input2;
    String input3;
    // Getters and Setters.
}
```

Or is this against REST GET specification and I cannot use Java POJO object as input parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the specification of HTTP protocol with **GET** method *no body can be supplied*. E.g. you can pass data only as part of URI.

Actually, you can supply object via GET method. Just convert it into text (like JSON), encode it into *base64* (because some symbols like spaces are not allowed in URI), put that content into `input1` path variable (e.g. `/URI/encodedpojohere`). Then decode `input1` string on server and convert it back to Java's POJO.

This approach has several limitations (the most obvious of them is limited length of URI string - something about 65535 symbols). And inefficiency (you cannot transmit arbitrary sequence of bytes and need to encode them). Perhaps, this is why there are not any standard convertors/annotations/helper classes for transmitting POJOs via GET request. So use **POST** or **PUT** methods instead. Spring and other frameworks have a bunch of utility classes/annotation for them.

---

Generally, it's possible to supply a body within HTTP GET method. Such approach was discussed there: [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body). Some well-known products, for example, [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_introducing_the_query_language.html) provides queries like this:

```
GET /bank/_search
{
  "query": { "match_all": {} }
}
```

(corresponding HTTP request can be executed via **curl** command line utility)

Anyway, HTTP GET with body is non-standard. Perhaps, this is why it's not supported in Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Path("/injectdemo")
```

public class TestClass {

```
//URI: http:URI/injectdemo/create?queryparam={"input1" : "XYZ", "input2" : "ABC", "input3" : "DEF"}
@GET
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/create")
public InputPojo postMsg(@QueryParam("queryparam") String jsonString) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    //Method 1: Convert Json String to required pojo
    InputPojo inputPojo = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, InputPojo.class);

    //Method 2: Convert Json String to required pojo
    InputPojo inputPojo1 =new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, InputPojo.class);


    return inputPojo;
}
```

}

> The JSON string can be sent in URI as: http:URI/injectdemo/create?queryparam={"input1" : "XYZ", "input2" : "ABC", "input3" : "DEF"}. It worked for me. But its not a good practice as Uri would be too long if the Pojo is healthy i.e. too many variables.